# Semantic HTML5 element properties

Tags: html

HTML5 introduced many [semantic elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) (`<nav>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, etc.).  But aside from helping read and structure our HTML, do they have any other unique properties?  Or are they essentially  just `<div>`s with different names?  It seems like the latter is true.

I keep reading about the "semantics" but can't find a direct answer.

Comment: For the most part - yes, they're essentially just divs but designed with specific use cases in mind. They don't even map to unique interfaces in the DOM, unlike div which maps to HTMLDivElement. You can use a div for just about anything because it doesn't mean anything on its own, but a nav is a nav and it's inappropriate to use it for something that is emphatically not a navigation section for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, etc., elements don’t have any special properties that are exposed to frontend JavaScript code; instead they all just use [the `HTMLElement` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement).

However, they do have special properties in screen readers—in that they get announced to screen-reader users in a special way that a `div` element doesn’t.

Screen readers can announce that a certain part of a document is a `section` or `article`, and allow screen-reader users to navigate through the document `section`-by-`section`, or to more easily jump among `article`s.

That said, screen readers also enable users to easily navigate through a document by jumping among its `h1`-`h6` headings—regardless of whether those headings are in `section` or `article` elements—so for screen-reader users it’s actually more important that your documents have good informative `h1`-`h6` headings and a logical structure.

Comment: I'm not up to speed on adoption of HTML5 semantic elements by AT, but if screen readers do indeed recognize and support these elements, that's good to know.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah part of the way the requirements for how particular HTML elements are exposed to screen readers is through a normative “HTML Accessibility API Mappings” spec defining mappings that browsers must use to particular platform accessibility APIs for, e.g., MacOS, Linux, and Microsoft Windows—to quite some degree of complexity in some cases; see for example https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aam-1.0/#el-section. The support is not perfect in part due to bugs that browsers need to fix—but there are things like http://www.html5accessibility.com/HTML5ASS/ that score/track the level of support

Comment: See also http://www.html5accessibility.com/#sections for detailed report on the level of accessibility support for `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, etc., elements in browsers—including how closely they conform to the requirements for mapping the elements to platform accessibility APIs (and thus to screen readers) in the right way, and also including links to open browser bugs for any particular known issues

Comment: See also the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938014/proper-heading-for-a-table/41939099#41939099 for an example of how current limitations in some browsers can influence your markup choices, as far as ensuring your documents are accessible to screen-reader users in the way you’d expect

Answer (score 0):

Semantic elements are elements that describe the content. They provide more information to the browser without requiring any extra attributes.

**Considering Microformats**
When you’re adding semantics into your web pages, you should consider using microformats to add even more meaning, when appropriate. Microformats use human-readable text inside the HTML (usually in the class attribute of an element) to define the contents.

Microformats add semantic information about the elements, and this information is already being used in certain situations.

[image]

Above figure shows a Google search for reviews of the movie Ender’s Game. The second and third results show “rich snippets,” including information like the star rating.

Google and Bing are both using these types of rich snippets to enhance their search results, and most of the data they are using to get it is semantically marked-up HTML using microformats. You can learn more about how to use microformats in my book Sams Teach Yourself HTML5 Mobile Application Development in 24 Hours.

By writing semantic HTML, you give more information to user agents to use to display the information correctly. For example, if a screen reader sees the  element, it knows that this is the main point of the page, and it will read it aloud before reading anything in an  element. Plus, as web pages get more and more sophisticated, what the user agents do with them gains sophistication. For instance, in the future, your semantically marked-up recipe could tell a web-ready refrigerator what time to alert the robot butler to start the roast.