# Do HTML5 tags has special properties and behaviors?

Tags: html

From what I've read, HTML5 new tags like `section` `header` `article` give meaning and readability to a web page instead using too many meaningless divs.

However, my question is: Do they have any special behavior or limitations in browsers or CSS properties?

This question came to me when I knew that `<img>` tags can't have pseudo elements `:before, :after`

So what other tags have some differences?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073757/semantic-html5-element-properties/45073882#45073882

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In a way

**All tags in HTML do something that do other tags do.**

However, while some tags (like `<img>`, as you have found) restrict what you can do, and others provide functionality (such as `<button>` or `<video>`), some offer more of a semantic role.

When being rendered on the page, these elements may not appear any different to other elements (for some, such as `<blockquote>`, browsers may provide default styles, however these should not be relied upon as they will be different / non-existent on other browsers or Operating Systems), they still provide functionality.

### How?

- Screenreaders will use semantic elements to change their tone of voice, volume, or announce a new section, etc, depending on semantic tags;
- Services such as Google will scan pages and find content based around semantic tags (for example, they could be used when creating [featured snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en))

There are many other use cases. It is mainly so that computers (and other programmers looking at your code) can understand immediately what each element can contain. We can look at a website and see an item's styles to figure out it's a navbar, but a computer's job is made easier if it is a `<nav>` rather than `<div class="second-navi-bar">`, etc.

### In Summary...

Semantic elements provide structure for your site's code, rather than styles for it's users. For those semantic elements that do provide styles (such as `<code>` or `<blockquote>`), these styles will change depending on your browser - you should always style semantic elements yourself.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, really appreciate your response and knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

They are called [semantic elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#Semantic_elements)

They don't typically behave differently while being rendered by the browser. Usually, they're used by search engines or other applications which parse the data on a website.