# Header or Legend?

Tags: css, html, forms

I am working on an admins panel website.
All pages have an header and some form below it.

a page looks something like this:

```
<div class="page some-page">
     <form>
        <fieldset>
           ...
        </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
```

I need to add a header for all the pages and I wonder if to put it as a `<legend>` - or as `<H1>`

---

so each page header can be something like this (using legend):

```
<div class="page some-page">
     <form>
        <fieldset>
           <legend>Page's Header</legend>
           ...
        </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
```

or like this (using h1)

```
<div class="page some-page">
     <h1>Page's Header</h1>
     <form>
        <fieldset>
           ...
        </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
```

or maybe even something more complicated with nested header > h1:

```
<div class="page some-page">
     <header>
         <h1>Page's Header</h1>
     </header>
     <form>
        <fieldset>
           ...
        </fieldset>
     </form>
</div>
```

In terms of design and css-ing it - all are the same and can be styled the same..

---

from the HTML specification -  is:

> The HTML – elements represent six levels of section headings.  is the highest section level and  is the lowest.

and Legend is:

> The HTML  element represents a caption for the content of its parent .

---

I am asking in terms of "best practices" and HTML Specification.. maybe even taste -

How do you would implement the header for all the pages?

Comment: I normally just use the `<h1>` tags for headers but I never use the fieldsets tag in my forms. If you are actually using `<fieldset>` and the "header" is defining the caption for the fieldset I would probably use `<legend>` since that is its specific use. "The <legend> tag defines a caption for the <fieldset> element."  Otherwise, I would use the `<h1>` for any other sort of "header". Also since this is for an "Admin Panel" I do not think that this will matter in terms of SEO since it will be behind a login and crawlers cannot get to it.

Comment: Hi @Matthew thx. yes. you absolutely right. in this case SEO is irrelevant.. but I wonder what is the preferred choice, let say for public sites, when all the page is a big form. should we use h1 or legend?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is off topic here and should be asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com. However, the questions about the elements are off topic there and the question ventures on opinion here.

Comment: Honestly, I would say it is really personal preference since both would be valid. I would tend to lean more towards the `h1` tag though because it can be used more freely. Bottom line, it's up to you.

Comment: @Rob This is not SEO related question. This is best practice use of HTML specification related question

Comment: In your question you said you are "asking in terms of SEO and HTML"

Comment: @Rob. Because I am not sure what the difference is.. is using H1 or Legend is the same? not even any difference in terms of SEO?

Comment: @Rob, I know he said SEO in his question but from reading his question SEO does not even apply since it is behind an admin panel. I have edited the question to say "best practices" instead of SEO because that is more fitting.

Comment: @Matthew You shouldn't edit his words that way. It changes his intent as he said to me in a comment.

Comment: @ET-CS Just look at the spec and you'll see it's clearly laid out what each element is to be used for.

Comment: @Matthew I suspect too that it's a matter of personal preference, but if that's true - there it doesn't really matter if you use <h1> , or <h2> too.. or even <p> or <div> are good for that matter too..

Comment: @Rob, He agreed that the SEO part is irrelevant which is why I changed it. His intent is to figure out what is the best practice.

Comment: @ET-CS you can use a <p> or a <div> but that would not be "best practice" for what you would be using it for. the <h#> tag is specifically meant for "headers" the <p> tag is meant for paragraphs and a <div> is meant to be a wrapper for the content shown.

Comment: @Matthew I've edited and added the specifcation title from MDN. both suitable, and both not mentioned as a top page header. I think the question is if a page can live without H1..

Comment: absolutely it can live with an `<h1>` tag.

Comment: @Matthew. Thanks for an interesting talk. I am learning to H1 too.. maybe just because I am used to it... but I think there is some sense to use legend instead when the page is just one form..
when multiple forms are on page, I see why one can use legend on each, and H1 for the entire page.. so maybe that's the answer.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41938014/1016716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<h1>` for the most important heading for a page.

Use a `<fieldset>` to group a collection of form fields together. Don't use it to contain the entire form. For example:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Your name</legend>
  <label><input> Salutation</label><br>
  <label><input> Forename</label><br>
  <label><input> Surname</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Your address</legend>
  <label><input> House name or number</label><br>
  <label><input> Street</label><br>
  <label><input> Town</label><br>
  <label><input> Post code</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Animals you like</legend>
  <label><input type=checkbox> Cats</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox> Dogs</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox> Horses</label>
</fieldset>
```

(These are not ideal examples of HTML or how to capture names or addresses, but they demonstrate how to use fieldsets).

Fields do not have to go into fieldsets. Most forms do not need fieldsets at all. They are just there for when you need to group a collection of fields with a common label.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb of semantic markup is to think not about how the elements display on the page but *what role the elements actually play* as anatomical components of the document.

In this instance, I would go for something like this:

```
<body>
<h1>Page's Header</h1>

...

<main class="page some-page">

'''

<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>...</legend>
...
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
<legend>...</legend>
...
</fieldset>
</form>

...

</main>

...

</body>
```